# How to delete the information from dynamically created table

Tags: javascript, forms, dynamic, html-table

```
<table>
<form>         
<tr><td colspan="4"><div id="myTableData" style="display:none;"><table><tr><td width="175">NAME</td><td width="245">&nbsp;Gender</td><td width="245">Date of Birth</td></tr></table></div></td></tr>
                 <tr><td colspan="4"><input type="button"  value="ADD KID " onClick="addrow()" />
<tr><td><input type="submit" name="reg"  value="" class="submitbut" onclick="chkform()"/></td></tr>
        </table>

          </form>
    <script>
     function addrow() {

                document.getElementById("myTableData").style.display="block";

                  var el = document.createElement('input');
                      el.type = 'text';
                      el.name = 'kname';

                  var del = document.createElement('input');
                      del.type = 'button';
                      del.name = 'delll';
                      del.value = 'del';


                  var el_r = document.createElement('input');
                      el_r.type = 'radio';
                      el_r.name = 'gender';
                      el_r.value ='FEMALE';
                      el_r.id = "rad1";  
                      el_r.defaultChecked = true;   


                  var el_r2 = document.createElement('input');
                      el_r2.type = 'radio';
                      el_r2.name = 'gender';
                      el_r2.value ='MALE';
                      el_r2.id = "rad2";  
                   var obj1 = document.createTextNode("Female");  
                   var obj2 = document.createTextNode("Male");  

                   var objLabel = document.createElement("label");  
                    objLabel.htmlFor = el_r.id;  
                    objLabel.appendChild(el_r);  
                    objLabel.appendChild(obj1);

                   var objLabel2 = document.createElement("label");  
                    objLabel2.htmlFor = el_r2.id;  
                    objLabel2.appendChild(el_r2);  
                    objLabel2.appendChild(obj2);  

                   var el_s = document.createElement('select');
                       el_s.onchange =  function(){ 
                       var r = el_s.options[el_s.selectedIndex].value;

                        }


                  for(var i=0;i<32;i++)
                  {
                     var j = i;
                      j = document.createElement('option');
                      j.text=i;
                      j.name="day";
                      j.value=j;
                      el_s.appendChild(j);
                  }
                  var month = new Array("January","Februray","March","April","May","June","July","August","September","October","November","December");
                  var el_sm = document.createElement('select');
                  for(var i=0;i<month.length;i++)
                  {
                     var j = i;
                      j = document.createElement('option');
                      j.text=month[i];
                      j.name="month";
                      j.value=month[i];
                      el_sm.appendChild(j);
                  }

                  var el_sy = document.createElement('select');
                  for(var i=2013;i>1950;i--)
                  {
                     var j = i;
                      j = document.createElement('option');
                      j.text=i;
                      j.name="year";
                      j.value=j;
                      el_sy.appendChild(j);
                  }



                var table = document.getElementById("myTableData");
                var tableBody = document.createElement('TBODY');
                table.appendChild(tableBody);

                   var tr = document.createElement('TR');
                   tableBody.appendChild(tr);

                       var td = document.createElement('TD');
                       td.width='175';
                       td.appendChild(el);
                       tr.appendChild(td);

                       var td = document.createElement('TD');
                       td.width='245';
                       td.appendChild(objLabel);
                       td.appendChild(objLabel2);
                       tr.appendChild(td);

                       var td = document.createElement('TD');
                       td.width='245';
                       td.appendChild(el_s);
                       td.appendChild(el_sm);
                       td.appendChild(el_sy);
                       tr.appendChild(td);

                       var td = document.createElement('TD');
                       td.width='20';
                       td.appendChild(del);
                       tr.appendChild(td);

                      myTableData.appendChild(table);

            }

            </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

There is a div which is hidden but when I click the add kid button the div is shown with 4 columns named name gender and date of birth and delete.

I have dynamically created a table on button click addkid , AND now I want to remove the whole  row containing information if delete button named (del) is clicked  how is it possible. 
The whole thing is in form which works on submit.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#myTableData').find('tr').each(function(){
   $(this).remove(); // remove element 
})
```

with pure javascript you could do:

```
var table = document.getElementById('myTableData');
var trs = table.getElementsByTagName('tr');
var dad = trs[0].parentNode;

for(var i = 0; i < trs.length; i++){
   dad.removeChild(trs[i]);
}
```

Comment: i dont want to use jquery in this can i do this in jaavscript

Comment: Yep the second piece of code deletes all trs with pure javascript as I posted.